# Is it possible to run ELK as a Docker service?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, elastic-stack

I am new to Docker world and trying to run ElasticSearch stack on Docker. I am able to start the ELK as an Container and it works perfectly.

```
docker run -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/elk-data:/var/lib/elasticsearch \
-v /var/lib/docker/volumes/elk-data:/var/log/elasticsearch \
-p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200  -p 5044:5044 \
--name elk sebp/elk
```

I am using journalbeat to forward the metrics to ElasticSearch service and do visualization in Kibana.

I was able to run journalbeat as a service using the following command:

```
sudo docker service create --replicas 2 --mount type=bind,source=/opt/apps/shared/dev/docker/volumes/journalbeat/config/journalbeat.yml,target=/journalbeat.yml --mount type=bind,source=/run/log/journal,target=/run/log/journal --mount type=bind,source=/etc/machine-id,target=/etc/machine-id --constraint node.labels.nodename==devlabel --name journalbeat-svc mheese/journalbeat:v5.5.2
```

Is there a way can we run ELK as a service? so that we can start 2 containers - 1 one on Master Swarm and other on Worker Node.

Answer (score 3):

An example of running the full ELK stack as separate docker containers is available here: https://github.com/elastic/examples/tree/master/Miscellaneous/docker/full_stack_example

This uses docker-compose so you can easily bring the containers up and down.

Answer (score 2):

ELK means Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana, so there are 3 services that must be running. In Docker swarm a service has zero or more instances, but every instance is a container that is based on the same Dockerfile.

So, in order to run ELK as a service you would have to start Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana in the same container. Although theoretically it is possible, this is not recommended (there *should* be one process per container).

Instead, you should create 3 services, one for Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you provide an example code on how to start every service as a container? But I am interested in creating Docker service

Comment: @Aswin If you really want to start them inside a single container: https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/~/dockerfile/

Comment: @Aswin if you want to create 3 services: https://botleg.com/stories/log-management-of-docker-swarm-with-elk-stack/

Comment: We are using docker version 1.12. I heard docker-compose works only after 1.13 pls confirm

Comment: @Aswin I don't know. You could try to see if it works.